# Searching a number in a specific string with regexp in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to find a specific number from a HTML response. 
For example, I want to extract **3** from `publicationID3publicationID`.
Does someone know a solution with regexp?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please clarify your question; what have you tried doing, and what exactly isn't working? Also, your example link is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) Post Processor **as a child** of the request, which returns to you this string.

Configure it as follows:

- Reference Name: `publicationID` (you can use any variable name here)
- Regular Expression: `publicationID(\d+)publicationID`
- Template: `$1$`

other fields can be left blank.

You can later refer publication ID as `${publicationID}` or `${__V(publicationID)}`

You can see what matches does your Regular Expression return using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener (select RegExp Tester from dropdown). Another option is [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) again with combination with View Results Tree.

Answer (score -1):

you can use \d to match a number using regex.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, just states one of the features of regex.